# Family reunification for a person who has a 1 year Titre de séjour salarié (France)

Tags: visa, immigration, france, family

I want to know when I can start my family reunification after my change of student status to employee .... Or is it better to wait until the end of your first year as an employee. Because I have heard that I needed to be living in France for 18 months (does it include the months before you got your Carte or does it start right after you get your Carte)

Details:

I came to France in late Oct 2015 for my masters. Graduated in 2017 with my masters and I got married in Aug 2017. I came back to France in March 2018 (with my student visa/didn't expire) And I would go back and forth from my home country and France until Oct 2018 where I stayed in France from Oct to August (I requested for a Carte in Feb 2019 and got it in August) I came back to my home country for the entire month of August and came back to France on sept 22.

I just made my change of status from student to employee. I got my carte in early August and I have a one year Carte de séjour salarié.

Worked as a IT Developer for a new site and I'm currently in a Pizzera working.

Questions:

1. Do my student years not count towards the 18 month residency and if they don’t does that mean I have to start since August when I got my first *titre*?
2. I found a apartment but I have not moved yet but I want to make someone else live it in (like my parents when they come to visit) Is that ok to do? Since I will be changing my address on my *titre*

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is two questions in one. You should probably ask point 2 in a second question.

Answer (score 1):

The [government website](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11166) on the matter says you require:

> Séjour régulier
>
> L'étranger, à l'origine de la demande de regroupement, doit résider depuis au moins 18 mois en France avec un des titres suivants :
>
> - Carte de séjour d'au moins 1 an (mention salarié, vie privée et familiale, étudiant visiteur, etc.)
> - Carte de résident ou carte de résident de longue durée-UE (délivrée par la France) de 10 ans
> - Récépissé de demande de renouvellement d'un de ces titres.

In which they mention student *carte de séjour*. So I would expect it to be valid for the residency you gained as a student. 
In addition to this, you will need to proof sufficient financial resources, and having a place to live.

Now, please not that I am no expert in immigration procedures, and the best you can do is ask the relevant administration to confirm your status and what you have to do. They might ask for proof of effective residence in the country during the whole period, and prolonged travel to your home country might be excluded.